# AWS Lambda in Java, with Windows?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services

I am reading the tutorial on using AWS Lambda with Java to create a jar or zip deploy package.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-create-jar-pkg-maven-no-ide.html

The tutorials just mention Linux and Mac OS. Can that procedure be used on Windows too? (By installing Maven on Windows?). Or is there any other best practices to run Java on AWS Lambda and developing on Windows?

Comment: The same process should work on Windows. Let us know if you run into an issue.